# React and Typescript, Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string but got: undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

I have project in react which was recently rewritten to typescript. Now, after modifications, when I want to add one component I recived an error:

*"Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports."*

This is my index.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, Alert } from "react-native";
import Screen from "../../components/Screen";
import FormField from "../../components/InputText";
import { Formik as FormComponent } from "formik";
import SubmitButton from "../../components/buttons/SubmitButton";

import ImagePicker  from "../../components/forms/ImagePickerForm";



const AddItem = () => {
  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <Screen>
        <ImagePicker />

        <FormComponent
          initialValues={{ title: "", description: "", category: "", images: [] }}
          onSubmit={(values) => Alert.alert("Correct!")} //{(values) => console.log(values)}
          validationSchema={validationSchema}
        >
          {({ handleChange, errors }) => (
            <>

              {/*<Text>{errors.category}</Text>*/}

              <FormField
                name="title"
                placeholder="title"
                onChangeText={handleChange("title")}
                style={{ width: "100%", flex: 1 }}
                maxLength={70}
                multiline
                width={100}
              ></FormField>

              <Text>{errors.title}</Text>

          

              <SubmitButton title="Add item" />
            </>
          )}
        </FormComponent>
      </Screen>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};



export default AddItem;
```

And this is component which Im trying to add to my index.tsx as `<ImagePicker/>`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';

import ImageInput from "../ImageInput";


const PickImage: React.FC<{}> = () => {
  const [imageUri, setImageUri] = useState();

  const selectImage = async () => {
    try {
      const result: any = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync();
      if (!result.cancelled) setImageUri(result.uri);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("something went wrong");
    }
  };
  return <ImageInput imageUri={imageUri} onChangeImage={(uri) => setImageUri(uri)} />;
}

export default ImagePicker;
```

Any idea why I recived an error?
I will be greatfull for help with this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are exporting by default `ImagePicker` instead of `PickImage`

Answer (score 3):

When you're exporting ImagePicker, it's using ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker". You need to export default PickImage.